# Share network from windows 8.1 to windows 8.1

Tags: windows-7, windows, networking, wireless-networking, windows-8.1

I'm trying to share network via "Connectify" from Windows 8.1 notebook to another Windows 8.1 notebook. And the problem is that connection is **limited**. Order isn't matter.

But third notebook with Windows 7 installed gets network well.

Also I have an android phone and the shared network via wifi from this phone works well on **any** device.

Comment: Sounds like a problem with connectify.  I would try another program

Comment: I'd guess that this is just because you're setup for DHCP and Connectify is setting up a p2p network between each client with ICS on the hotspot PC. You can probably setup a static IP without DHCP (I'd also use 8.8.8.8 for the DNS) and it should fix it if that is the case. http://www.tomshardware.com/faq/id-1928682/limited-connectivity-resolve-problem.html

Comment: @krowe, I did instructions step by step but it didn't help me.